# Same margin for different editText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm coding under android and I want to set the same `margin-left` to different editText. 
For now I just have `android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"` in each widget. I wonder if I can set a "style" or whatever to sum up this instruction.
Thx !

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a custom style and set that to your main app style.

**Step 1:** Create a custom EditText Style with all the styling you need

```
 <style name="MyEditTextStyle" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
     <item name="android:layout_marginLeft"=20dp</item>
    </style>
```

**Step 2:** Now add the style to your main app theme

```
<style name="App_Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
   ... 
   <item name="android:EditTextSyle">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
   ...
<style>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work... I don't use "@android:style/Theme.Holo" but  "Theme.AppCompat" as parent, I suppose it doesn't change anything...?

Comment: it doesn't matter which theme you are using yout just need to add 
<item name="android:EditTextSyle">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
to your parent theme.